# Javascript: button onclick function which will increase the HTML output number per click

Tags: javascript, html

Want to create a small application which have the function of counter and alarm. So there is two button, -1 and +1. When click the button, the number will continuesly change according to the time you click. So if click -1 button once, it will shows 0-1, if click -1 again, it will shows 0-2. [Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Hb5.png)

I try to use localstorage command to record each time when the button is clicked. I wondered is there other easier way to solve it.

Comment: what happen when the user clicked -1 twice and then clicked +1? should it show 0-2+1 or 0-1?

Comment: It should be 0-2+1.

Comment: you can manipulate the text on the button (using split for example) without saving the numbers, unless it should be saved when the page is being reload or closed